# wired networking not working after install and restart for security update

Tags: networking, network-manager

I was running 16.04.2 LTS today(2017/June/07) and did system update (reboot required) when I brought up the system the wired network was not working .

To get around this issue, I rebooted again in GRUB went to advanced, selected the previous `*-generic kernel vmlinuz-4.4.0.78-generic`.

I rebooted and networking is now working, before reboot went into "Network" system setting and noticed that there were no lines for "Wired".

This is my work PC so problem analysis will need to wait until later today (assuming I have the chance) to do some reboots
but initially looks like some type of NetManager update issue losing previous information and not auto detecting the network ...

Here are the relevant log entries:

```
NOTE 
george@njcvr25:/var/log/apt$ pwd
/var/log/apt
george@njcvr25:/var/log/apt$ more history.log

Start-Date: 2017-06-02  17:09:53
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.311'
Upgrade: libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.1, 2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.2), libsndfile1:amd64 (1.0.25-10, 1.0.25-10ubuntu0.16.0
4.1)
End-Date: 2017-06-02  17:09:56

Start-Date: 2017-06-02  17:10:03
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.311'
Upgrade: isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.3.3-5ubuntu12.6, 4.3.3-5ubuntu12.7), isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.3.3-5ubuntu12.6, 4.3.3-5ubuntu12.7
)
End-Date: 2017-06-02  17:10:07

Start-Date: 2017-06-06  07:51:02
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.174'
Upgrade: libtasn1-6:amd64 (4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.1, 4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.2)
End-Date: 2017-06-06  07:51:04

Start-Date: 2017-06-07  11:32:25
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.310'
Install: linux-signed-image-4.4.0-79-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-79.100, automatic), linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-79.100, au
tomatic), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-79.100, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-79:amd64 (4.4.0-79.100, automati
c), linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-79.100, automatic)
Upgrade: libnl-route-3-200:amd64 (3.2.27-1, 3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.78.84, 4.4.0.79.85), linu
x-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-78.99, 4.4.0-79.100), libnl-genl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.27-1, 3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), linux-image-generic:amd6
4 (4.4.0.78.84, 4.4.0.79.85), linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.78.84, 4.4.0.79.85), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.78.84
, 4.4.0.79.85), libnl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.27-1, 3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), lintian:amd64 (2.5.43, 2.5.43ubuntu0.1), linux-generic:amd6
4 (4.4.0.78.84, 4.4.0.79.85)
End-Date: 2017-06-07  11:33:49
george@njcvr25:/var/log/apt$
```

Comment: latest apt history log follows ...

Comment: I also received an update yesterday that forced me to restart, after restarting my network connection wasn't working. I simply disable networking and re-enabled it and everything worked after that. I did have an entry for wired network, so my problem might not be similar to yours. Just wanted to say that whatever that update was, it did mess with networking in some level

Comment: rebooted again with the same issue ... however this time when i went back to the older kernel networking was not working with that either ... seems to be a NetworkManager issue ... Next what I did was change /etc/network/interfaces to explicitly define my network ...

Comment: Filipe ... sounds like a good idea ... will try that next tomorrow when i come to work  ... today leaving for the day ... BTW ... my idea with the above change to interfaces ... i remembered something like this happening about a year ago and that was what i did to get networking working again ... did not think of stop and start of the network process

Comment: I still have an issue with networking ... it seems to be isolated with NetworkManager ... I have a network connection by manually editing /etc/network/interfaces ... but whenever i try to get connection information from network manager(GUI) ... it replies with "error displaying connection information: No valid active connections found!"

Comment: okay guys ... i got NetworkManager working by editing /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf .... changing managed=false to true ... but now when i reboot my PC the networking starts but seems to loose DNS and search settings ... this is becoming more and more arcane ... Does anyone know how to fully reset the NetworkManager configuration ... do I uninstall and then install again???  if I restart NetworkManager or networking it seems to work ...but the same thing happens again after a reboot